# Saving additional information to the database conditionally when using a modelfrom in django

Tags: python, django

I have a modelform and aside from the fields on the form i need to update one more column in the database depending on if there is a registered user submitting information or not. I read that you can use the save method with the argument "commit=False" which will create the database object but not save it to the database so i can check if the user is logged in and then also save additional information if i need to, and then call save myself. Does this seem like a reasonable approach to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly the right thing to do.

```
if form.is_valid():
    object = form.save(commit=False)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        object.user = request.user
    object.save()
```